# Bootstrap 3 animated columns when changing position media queries

Tags: jquery, html, css

```css
.bg1 {
    background: #111;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.bg2 {
    background: #222;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.bg3 {
    background: #333;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.bg4 {
    background: #444;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.bg5 {
    background: #555;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.bg6 {
    background: #666;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.bg7 {
    background: #777;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.bg8 {
    background: #888;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.bg9 {
    background: #999;
    padding:40px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg1"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg3"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg4"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg5"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg6"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg7"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg8"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class=" bg9"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/milindex/j1okznby/

We can make the columns to change positions in media Queries, do it with an effect, also on this site:

We Can see that when they change a responsive design mode, I have seen on this web site: http://www.joymovil.com/ upon activation Media Queries, it changes dynamically positions and a very stylish animation.

Comment: You might want to re-post the example websites of what you are trying to accomplish because I do not see your links.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, here is the link eg http://www.joymovil.com/

if you reduce the width of the browser, you'll see how all the elements are rearranged automatically, and with a purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I've found in order to accomplish what you are asking you will need to `absolute` position each of your columns on the page and then based on the media query widths you will use the `transition` property to move the columns. Here is a simple example with a [Js Fiddle to view](http://jsfiddle.net/y41hz9sz/). I got the example from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/animated-media-queries/).

HTML

```
<div class="dont-move">Doesnt move</div>
<div class="thing-that-moves">moves</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.dont-move {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
.thing-that-moves {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
    -o-transition: all .5s linear;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .thing-that-moves {
    left: 150px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I am not sure if this is possible using the bootstrap frame work with out some serious customization to the frame work it self. Bootstrap uses the grid system with its own media queries and does not use any positioning elements (that I am aware of). Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent, works very well, is a solution out of Bootstrap, but very good.