# How to add transition effect to a div in css on changing from col-12 to col-9?

Tags: angular, html, css, bootstrap-4

The below given css is working only when i close my div with class "onclick-div", But the transition effect is not seen when i click on the button i.e., when i wanted to reduce the width of the div with class "set-transition" from col-12 to col-9 i don't see the transition effect.

### My Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12 set-transition" [ngClass]="{'col-md-9' : dropDownVar === 2}">
    <button (click)="dropDownVar=2">+ ADD</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 onclick-div" *ngIf="dropDownVar === 2">
  </div>

</div>
```

### My Css:

```
.set-transition {
  transition:flex 0.5s ease;
  width:auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you try using `all` instead of `flex` and see if it works?

Comment: NO it's not working

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered previously here for bootstrap 3 
[Bootstrap 3 animated columns when changing position media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619331/bootstrap-3-animated-columns-when-changing-position-media-queries)

The method is still the same, using transition: all ...

```css
.show-transition {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 show-transition bg-dark text-light">Test</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work, i checked this solution before submitting this question.

Comment: I can run this and see it work.  What browser are you using and how are you verifying that it doesn't work?

Comment: Do i need to add any other style along with this?

Comment: Am using chrome, and the transition is working any when am closing the second div, but when am opening the second div it's not showing that transition effect

Comment: As you can see by the attached snippet, there are not other styles applied, only what you see here.